# Subscribe Powershell Information, Warning and Error stream AddData event

Tags: powershell

I'm building a wrapper around PowerShell scripts to handle logging in one unified way. The idea is to intercept messages from information/warning/error streams and log them in chronological order using different sinks (console/file/db etc). For that purpose, I'd like to utilize events that occur when some data is added to a corresponding stream. That's where I'm now:

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create("CurrentRunspace")
$ps.AddScript({
    Write-Information 'Information'
    Write-Warning 'Warning'
    Write-Error 'Error'
    exit -1
}) # in reality here should be script that is wrapped

$output = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[object]]::new()
$ps.Streams.Information.Add_DataAdded({
    # $output.Add($_) is for example, in reality, any handler could be added
    $ps.Streams.Information.ReadAll().ForEach{ $output.Add($_) }
})
$ps.Streams.Warning.Add_DataAdded({
    # $output.Add($_) is for example, in reality, any handler could be added
    $ps.Streams.Warning.ReadAll().ForEach{ $output.Add($_) }
})
$ps.Streams.Error.Add_DataAdded({
    # $output.Add($_) is for example, in reality, any handler could be added
    $ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll().ForEach{ $output.Add($_) }
})

# run script
$results = $ps.Invoke()
$exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE

# these lines are just for the test
Write-Host $exitCode
Write-Host "$([string]::Join(', ', $output))"
```

**Expected content of $output:**

```
-1
Information
Warning
Error
```

**Actual content of $output:**

```
-1
Error
```

Do you guys know why a subscription to the Warning and Information `DataAdded` event doesn't work?

Comment: Where are you querying the variable $output?  Output looks like it is just a new object with no data : $output = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[object]]::new()

Comment: @jdweng Example: $ps.Streams.Information.ReadAll().ForEach{ $output.Add($_) } - once the event is fired, the content is added to $output. Is that what you are asking about? You can play with the script in a shell to see the actual behavior